# How do I invoke ippiOpticalFlowPyrLK_16u_C1R?

Tags: c++, image-processing, intel-ipp

The [examples that I'm basing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/306312) my work on use `unsigned char` image; I have 16-bit unsigned images.  Doing the naive substitutions of `u8 -> u16` in the IPP function names doesn't work (I get compiler errors in some of the type casts).

Does anyone have a similar usage example for 16-bit (unsigned) images?

Basically it looks like `IppiPyramid` looks like it holds a pointer to an 8 bit image, which doesn't make sense since the 16 bit version is defined.

Comment: From the example on 32f types it looks like you must casting is in order. See: https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch14/ch14_example_of_using_general_pyramid_functions.html

Comment: @Steve -- thanks for that link -- I'll just recast the pointers as needed and see if it works.